# Repairing corrupted Pen Drive

Tags: usb-flash-drive, repair, format, windows-8.1

Last night, I formatted the Pen drive using Windows formatting tool.
Once the format was done, I pulled it out without using "Remove device safely".

Next time, I plugged in the device, the drive is showing up in Explorer.
But I am unable to open it, or format it.

[image]

I tried from Disk Management, by removing and re-adding driver letters. Still the same issue
from command prompt

```
There is no volume selected.
Please select a volume and try again.
```

It's MoserBear 16gb pen-drive. Please tell me how to fix this?

*Note: Used HDD Low Level Formatter, it's not recognizing this device.*

Comment: can you right click on it -> properties?

Comment: Step one:  Remove drive from computer and drop it in the round container by your desk.  Step two:  Purchase a new drive from the rack by the checkout counter of the local grocery.

Comment: You haven't mentioned which version of Windows 8 you are using, 32-bit or 64-bit?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Open up the Start Menu and type “diskpart” in the run box. Press enter. You’ll be prompted by the Windows UAC to authorize admin access to the DISKPART tool.

A command-prompt-like window will open up, only the prompt will say “DISKPART”. At that prompt, type “list disk”.
[image]

In the list output on our machine you can see the computer’s hard drive (119GB) and the removable SD card (14GB). It is absolutely critical you note the proper disk number. DISKPART commands are immediate and without any warning. If you type in the wrong disk number, you’re going to have a really bad time.

After identifying your SD card’s disk number, enter the following command “select disk #” where # is the disk number of your SD card.
[image]

Whatever commands you execute after this point will only make changes to the selected disk; now would be a good time to double check you’ve selected the right disk just to be extra safe.

Next, now enter the command “clean”
[image]

The clean command zeroes out the sectors of the disk that contain the partition data. If you wished to zero out all data on the SD card you could use “clean all” instead, but unless you have a pressing privacy/security reason for overwriting the the entire SD card with zeros, it’s unwise to waste the read/write cycles of the flash media.

After cleaning the disk, enter the following command “create partition primary”

[image]

The command, as the syntax implies, creates a new partition on the disk and sets it to primary. After creating the primary partition, the entire storage capacity of the SD card should be available to Windows. If we peek back into Disk Manager, we no longer see a tiny partition with a huge hunk of unallocated space, but a large partition ready to be formatted:

[image]

That’s all there is to it! A little DISKPART wizardy and the SD card is factory fresh again.

- extract of article from [here](http://www.howtogeek.com/170794/ask-htg-how-can-i-reclaim-the-full-capacity-of-an-sd-card/)

Comment: did you read my post?
I pasted the error from diskpart.

Please don't copy paste before reading the post

Comment: @NitinGurram - The error message said you didn't select the volume, hence, the directions about selecting the volume.

Comment: @NitinGurram , alternatley you may try dban which can be used to wipe data from storage devices in blanking mode and get it in raw form.then you may able to partition it from within windows.Or you may give a try to dd if you are using any linux distro.but this may cost you some write cycles.

Comment: dban:http://www.dban.org/download                                                                                         dd:http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dd_(Unix)

Comment: @DEFCON1, I will try it.

Comment: @Ramhound, indeed I selected and then try to do CLEAN.

Comment: This doesn't work for all buddy. Windows was not able to detect my pen-drive after I followed your steps. pravat231's answer worked for me!!

Answer (score 3):

**BOOTICE WILL SOLVE YOUR ISSUE**

[image]

Click on Parts Manage then you will find your partition then try to repartitioned it and then re-formating it.

THis will resolve your issue and again your USB starts working.

[Download BOOTICE](https://www.raymond.cc/blog/download/did/1727/)

Answer (score 0):

You can try [TestDisk](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk) it is one of the most most thorough data recovery program, but it has only command line interface. It is mainly used to recover lost data but it also have a repair funcionatality.

Comment: SOrry. it's not recognizing

Comment: How old is the pendrive? Maybe it come the end of his life, and there is a hardware error in it. I had have the same issue 1 years ago and this program is easily recognise my damaged external HDD, backup the contetn of it and after successfully repair the MTB on the disk. But google is your friend I also tried tons of programs before find this. I hope you find some great tools which will solve your problem!