# Formatting a corrupted pen drive

Tags: usb-flash-drive

Due to plugging my 4 gb kingston pen drive in a system having virus my pen drive got corrupted . When I plug in my pen drive I am not able to format it or use in it any manner. 
I tried using DISKPART tool as given [here](https://superuser.com/questions/640397/repairing-corrupted-pen-drive/640423#640423?newreg=b696691afb3946bc9251e0df150760ec).

but when using DISKPART tool my pen drive is not listed in the command prompt window. In my computer it is showing.
But when i try to open it I get following error.. Please help

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Open RUN and type this command

> diskmgmt.msc

Here all the disks will be listed you can format by right clicking the usb device.[image]

Comment: I tried this but was not able to do it. @vembutech

Comment: its not happening ... The blue drive which is being shown is not present and with right click this menu is not opening

Answer (score 0):

Connect the pen drive to your pc

Assuming the letter assigned to the pen drive is L,
[image]

RUN the command prompt **As Administrator**

Type the following command:

**format /q /x L:** and press enter
[image] press the enter
[image] 
[image]

format complete

Comment: After doing this message is displayed  

Insert new disk for drive H:
and press ENTER when ready